# Column Space of a matrix contained in Null Space of other matrix

Tags: vector-spaces

So I have $CS(A)$ is the subset of $NS(B)$. How do I show that $(AB)^2$ is zero matrix. $A$ and $ B$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any vector $x.$ Then $ABx\in \rm{CS}(A).$ Since $\rm{CS}(A)\subset \rm{NS}(B)$ we have that $BABx=0.$ So

$$(AB)^2x=ABABx=A0=0.$$ Since $x$ is arbitrary we conclude that $(AB)^2=0.$

Comment: I cannot understand why ABx belongs to CS(A).

Comment: If $y$ is any vector then $Ay\in \rm{CS}(A).$ Note that if $A=(A_1,\dots, A_n)$ (where $A_i$ denotes the column $i$) and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)^T$ then $Ay=y_1A_1+\dots +y_nA_n.$ That is, $Ay$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ and thus belongs to the column space.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you.